# why does counter outruns list length

Tags: python-3.x, list

```
longuer=int(input("input list lengh: "))
l1=list(range(longuer))
print('list lengh: '+str(longuer))
i=0
while i<len(l1):
    a=int(input("give number: "))
    l1.append(a)
    print("i="+str(i))
    i+=1
print(l1)
```

**code output** [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCu4N.png)

I don't understand why *'i'* outruns the length of the list ?
would love a good explanation with a fix for this please

Comment: "I don't understand why 'i' outruns the length of the list ?": It doesn't. You're adding to `l1` inside the loop, meaning `len(l1)` is constantly increasing. If you want it to be limited to what the user entered, you'd want `while i < longuer:`

Comment: The code doesn't make a ton of sense though. `l1` likely shouldn't be populated at the beginning. You likely just want `l1 = []`. Python lists aren't like arrays in other languages. You don't set their size when they're created.

Comment: @Carcigenicate thank you, code works now thanks to your pro tips (:

Comment: Np. But when in doubt, double check the data. If you had put a line like `print(len(l1), l1)` in the loop, the answer may have become obvious to you.

Answer (score 0):

```
longuer=int(input("input list lengh: "))
l1=[]
print('list lengh: '+str(longuer))
i=0
while i<longuer:
    a=int(input("give number: "))
    l1.append(a)
    print("i="+str(i))
    i+=1
print(l1)
```